# How to force LLVM to generate a single 'ret'?

Tags: return, llvm, code-generation

Consider the following LLVM IR:

```
@yyy = external dso_local global i32
@zzz = external dso_local global i64

define void @exec_xxx() {
entry:
  %0 = load i32, i32* @yyy, align 4
  %1 = icmp eq i32 %0, 0
  br i1 %1, label %bb_true, label %bb_false
bb_true:
  store i64 0, i64* @zzz, align 8
  br label %bb_false
bb_false:
  ret void
}
```

Here we see that it has a single `ret`. However, the [generated code](https://godbolt.org/z/oKWb59Ko4) has multiple `ret`:

```
exec_xxx:                               # @exec_xxx
        cmp     dword ptr [rip + yyy], 0
        je      .LBB0_1
        ret
.LBB0_1:                                # %bb_true
        mov     qword ptr [rip + zzz], 0
        ret
```

By some reason one need a single `ret` in the generated code.

Question: how to force LLVM to generate a single `ret`?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no builtin way to enforce this. Writing a machine function pass might be solution, there is an existing similar [pass](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/fe5cf480ee5ae0d14eb62f32e55a33d2ccf67dd1/llvm/lib/Target/X86/X86ReturnThunks.cpp) in backend that does replace every `ret` with `jmp`. [To get started.](https://www.kharghoshal.xyz/blog/writing-machinefunctionpass)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LLVMish answer to that is to write a pass. Passes is how LLVM modifies code.

In this case that'll be really simple, you'll need a class declaration that inherits `PassInfoMixin<>` and reimplements `run(Function &, FunctionAnalysisManager &)`. Your reimplementation should be 15-20 lines of code, I think.

I'll outline it in case you haven't written a pass before. It needs to iterate over the basic blocks and see whether [the terminator of each](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1BasicBlock.html#a33ebed8b6318e718721af90f7ef6c7bd) isa<ReturnInst>(), and add the ones that are to a list. After iterating you return early if there are fewer than two returns in the list.

Otherwise you make a new [basic block](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1BasicBlock.html#ace940beeee97c222f836fe0ac70f6cf5). If the return type isn't void you need to create a [phi node](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1PHINode.html#a058ec2d1d5a064fec8c0b2e59c5f0454) and populate it with incoming values from the returns, then create a return that returns the phi node. If it's void you make a new void return. Finally you replace all the old returns with branches to your new block. Done.

Comment: `opt -mergereturn`?

Comment: Indeed `-mergereturn` is the solution. Browsing the source I see it it was one of the first passes written in the early days of LLVM, so I assume doing this has a point. I wonder what the point is.

Comment: Hm, for the LLVM IR above `-mergereturn` does not cause single `ret`: `opt t67.ll -mergereturn > t67.opt.ll && llc t67.opt.ll && cat t67.opt.s | grep ret` produces `retq retq`. Any ideas?

Comment: @NickLewycky FYI: `-mergereturn` does not mean that generated asm code will contain signle `ret`. I need generated asm code containing signle `ret`. Any ideas?

Comment: @pmor Not as far as I know! The architecture of LLVM is one where your program in LLVM IR specifies the semantics of the program and LLVM emits native CPU code which meets that specification, and with optimization enabled does best effort at emitting code that runs quickly. You might be able to add this feature to LLVM yourself, or you might decide that LLVM is the wrong tool for the task if you need control over the generated assembly beyond it doing what the LLVM IR says. If it turns out this is a commonly requested feature the backend might have a flag for it, but I don't see one.

Comment: If you do try to add it to your own copy of LLVM, look into "AMDGPUUnifyDivergentExitNodes.cpp" from lib/Target/AMDGPU. That might help you get started.

Comment: @NickLewycky My colleague has found `--tail-dup-placement=0`, which [seems to work](https://godbolt.org/z/GG751TeGW). However, I cannot find a documentation for `--tail-dup-placement`. Perhaps "write a pass" (as recommended by user arnt) is already done in `--tail-dup-placement`? How can you comment?

Comment: That flag is part of machine block placement pass. The description is "Perform tail duplication during placement. Creates more fallthrough opportunites in outline branches."  As far as I call tell, this adjusts heuristics for machine block placement, but does not provide a hard guarantee of that there will only be one `ret`. Regardless, you may wish to look into `lib/CodeGen/MachineBlockPlacement.cpp`.

Comment: Here's a simple example that emits two `ret`s even with that flag: https://godbolt.org/z/sMGY67jhG

Comment: I'm curious. What's the point of guaranteeing a single `ret`? What benefit does such a guarantee provide?

Comment: @NickLewycky Re: "does not provide a hard guarantee": useful to know, thanks.

Comment: @arnt Re: "What's the point": to have a binary code with "one entry - one exit". The "multiple exits" is not really an issue, however, in that case more logic is required to handle multiple exits. The "one entry - one exit" simplifies the logic.

Comment: Oh, I see. I wrote something like that too once. I had to write the extra logic almost at once, when my code encountered a function with zero returns (a main() that reacted to network input, looping infinitely).